# What's "@+node"?

Tags: jquery, python, bottle

I'm trying to extend a Python + BottlePy script. I ran into a problem where my POST data are becoming `Null` during transmission, so I dived a little deeper into the code. In the web site templates, I found strings like `<!--@+node:ngerum.20120101211222.1350: *3* settings-->`, what do they mean? I didn't find anything in the BottlePy documentation and the only other used library is jQuery.

Comment: I'm not familiar with BottlePy, but assuming the template is HTML, that appears to be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's anything to do with Bottle or jQuery.

Perhaps an cloud email provider like GMail or HotMail that inserted these strings for internal tracking though, because the *only* other reference I can find in google is a reposted forum post with two such nodes in the body text, right after an email address:

http://baexpats.org/expat-life/930-storage-awhile.html